# In Jupyter sometimes the `?` operator works on an instance of a class, and sometimes it requires a generic class. Why is that?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

In a Jupyter notebook, sometimes the `?` operator will work on an instance of an object, and sometimes it will say `Object 'some_object' not found`.

It will still work on the generic class/function.

`?df.plot` will not work, but `?pd.DataFrame.plot` does.

However, both `?df.describe` and `?pd.DataFrame.describe` work.

It seems that help(whatever) always finds the docstring, so...

[image]

What's the pattern?

Comment: `?df.plot` works.

Comment: Are you sure `df` had been defined at that point?  `pd.DataFrame().plot?` doesn't work because `?` does not evaluate the expression.  But first `df=pd.DataFrame()` and `df.plot?` should work.

Comment: Just realized that I'm actually looking at a Series, but still, I think the question stands.

Comment: I added an image. I don't think I'm using an uninstantiated variable, or calling any functions unnecessarily.

Comment: The argument of the help is evaluated, returning a bound method.  `help` gets its docs. I don't know exactly what `?` is doing, but it is not evaluating the `df[x]` step, so can't find the appropriate method.

Comment: [94] is not what you first asked about.

Comment: How should I have phrased it?

Comment: After sleeping on it, I think I see what you mean. 

There is no "Series" object because the '?' prevents the column index from being evaluated.